# Rails Submit Form Remote issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, remote-forms

I am trying to submit a form via `remote: true` in rails 3 and for some reason when I look at the response in the browser I only see the raw response instead of the JavaScript being interpreted.

Form:

```
<%= form_for @entry, url: contest_entries_path, remote: true, html: {id: "contest_form"} do |f| %>
```

Controller:

```
class ContestEntriesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @entry = ContestEntry.new
    @entry.build_school
    respond_with @entry
  end

  def create
    @entry = ContestEntry.new(params[:contest_entry])
    respond_with @entry
  end
end
```

Create.js.erb:

```
<% unless @entry.errors.any? %>

        <% if @entry.parent? %>
            $('body').find('#parents_message').show();
        <% else %>
            $('body').find('#falculty_message').show();
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The response in the browser is the raw JavaScript response

Comment: There might be a problem with the response Javascript that you're returning. An easy way to test is to copy the response JavaScript and paste it into something like Firebug console and see the result.

Comment: I've seen this before as well and I think it's potentially an issue in the documentation, but have you tried moving the `remote: true` inside the `html` hash? Most likely the `data-remote` attribute isn't being added to the `form` element.

Comment: It actually wound up being me misspelling the div tag I was calling inside of the JS call :(